# How to fix weird bug with <option> tag in Experience Editor?

Tags: sxa

Does anyone get this weird issue when you are using `<select>` input tag, and inside the selec tag the the `<option>` tag. Everything works perfectly fine in Preview Mode but inside the Experience Editor it shows something really weird.

Here is the image to show you what I mean by this:

### Console

[image]

### View in Experience Editor

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code for showing Title value in the page if you are using it under head tag:

**Html.Sitecore().Field("Field Name", new { DisableWebEdit = true })**

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by not using the `@Html.Sitecore.Field("Title")` as a field value I just used for example `@item["Title"]` to get the value of the item